# Pythonic way to make sure list exists at dict key before appending

Tags: python

I'm asking this from the perspective that my impression is that it's more Pythonic to ask forgiveness than permission.

So, I've got some code that's like:

```
d = dict()
try:
    d[est['state']].append(est)
except Exception:
    d[est['state']] = []
    d[est['state']].append(est)
```

In the above code I ask forgiveness rather than permission at the expense of repeating myself, which is pretty lame! So, knowing no alternative, I would rather:

```
d = dict()
if est['state'] in d:
    d[est['state']].append(est)
else:
    d[est['state']] = [est]
```

Both of these approach are sort of gnarly. What's a better way to do this? Best I've found so far is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d[est['state']].append(est)
```

Comment: Yup, use a `defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault` if you don't have 2.5. I think you've answered your own Q :)

Comment: `defaultdict` is awesome. Now if only `defaultOrderedDict` was in the stdlib...

Comment: Totally missed `dict.setdefault`. Looks like it's similar to `dict.get` but will set the default in addition to returning the key's value. Wild!

Comment: well, your first example escapes branch prediction, if your worried about speed, I would test the two different examples for their performance (if it is in a performance critical area of your code). As for design though, the first example definately is more error prone and harder to read then the later example.

Comment: Less worried about speed and more about readability/maintainability. Yeah, it does appear the last version is the best, but depends on 2.5+

Comment: Most people don't need 2.4 compatibility anymore. And if you do, I'd suggest using the pure-python backport of `defaultdict` on PyPI or the ActiveState recipes, so you can just write the same code, with a couple extra lines at the top to deal with pre-2.5 compat.

Comment: As for why `defaultOrderedDict` isn't there: I've seen at least two threads where people suggest this, which degenerate into discussions on the difference between an ordered default dict and a default ordered dict (which makes a difference in certain cases where you subclass it) that never come to a conclusion. Ultimately, the simple case is very easy to code yourself (`defaultdict` and `OrderedDict` are both pure Python and easy to read, and copy into your code and hack on), so nobody's cared enough to push it through.

Comment: That, and the oft-cited argument that 90% of the time a newbie thinks they need `OrderedDict`, they don't actually need it, so it's a bad idea to encourage it any further than it already is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pythonic way is the latter you have already discovered: [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) is a dict subclass that calls a factory function to supply missing values.  It is available in python 2.5 and up.

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> d[0].append('potato')
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['potato']})
```

It exists for precisely this purpose, so avoid `dict.setdefault` hacks if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might try benchmarking a few different approaches if you're concerned about speed. I've tried the "if key in dictionary" approach, and found try/except to be about 10% faster on average. I find that my Python best-practices in these kinds of questions change every few years. This answer may be helpful if you need compatibility with Python 2.4.

Using your example, I would have:

```
d = {}

# Confirm separately that est['state'] does not raise a KeyError.

state = est['state']

try:
    l = d[state]
except KeyError:
    l = []
    d[state] = l

l.append(est)
```